# Is it possible to save zip file read from http and directly saving it to Databse without creating it physically in java

Tags: java, database, hibernate, url, zip

I am reading zip file from url now I want to save it directly to databse without storing it physically using java and hibernate.

I am reading zip file as,

```
    URLConnection  uCon = null;
    URL Url;
    byte[] buf;     
    ZipOutputStream outStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("mytest.zip"));
    Url= new URL(http://xyz.com/pages/info.doc);
    uCon = Url.openConnection();
    is = uCon.getInputStream();
    buf = new byte[size];
    is = uCon.getInputStream();
    outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("info.doc"));
    while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) 
              {     
    outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
    ByteWritten += ByteRead;
    }
    is.close();
    outStream.close();
```

I dont want to save "mytest.zip" physically once it is created I want to save it directly in DB ? Is it possible ? How it can be done ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of writing to a `FileOutputStream`. The use the `getBytes()` method of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to get the byte array, in memory, containing the bytes of the zip file.

Create a prepared statement as you would do to insert any kind of data into a database table, and use its `setBinaryStream()` or `setBlob()` method to fill one of the column with the content of the byte array. You just need to pass a `ByteArrayInputStream` (constructed with the byte array as argument) to one of these methods.

Comment: Thanks JB.Using setBlob() content will be saved in DB. What if I want to save that content by some name say "test.zip" ?

Comment: That should be another field in the DB table. A BLOB has no standard SQL extension (fortunately) and is handled like other types, with one value, the data. _One could store a zip of a zip._

Answer (score 2):

Use a pipe to keep low memory needs - setBlob(colunm, InputStream) -, and use IOUtils.copy to have fast copying.

```
    PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream(pipeOut);

    setBlob(pipeIn);

    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(pipeOut, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("info.doc"));
    IOUtils.copy(sourceIn, zipOut); // org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    zipOut.closeEntry();
    zipOut.close();
```

*This still is without `try`s and a second thread would be nice.*

Comment: Thanks again. I wanted to give name to zip file. with outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("info.doc"));  this will be name inside zip file. How I can give name to zip file. With new FileOutputStream("mytest.zip) I am able to give it. But now using ByteArrayOutputStream  how name can be given to zip file ?

Comment: In a database blob field the zip content may be filled. One has to store the file name separately in its own field.